# Add missing rows to SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data set in which I need each issue to have 3 rows. 1 for each status that is possible. Below is an example of what I currently have.

```
Issue  Status  Time 
-------------------
1      SLM      30
1      SNB      43
1      EOB      22
2      SLM      12
2      EOB      87
```

I need something like this, where is an issue doesn't have a status then a row is added and 0 is set for the time.

```
 Issue   Status    Time 
 ----------------------
    1      SLM      30
    1      SNB      43
    1      EOB      22
    2      SLM      12
    2      EOB      87
    2      SNB      0
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you have a table that contains the three types of Status values?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cross join id's with statuses and left join the table on to that.

```
select i.issue,s.status,coalesce(t.time,0) as time
from (select distinct status from tbl) s --replace this with status table if you have one
cross join (select distinct issue from tbl) i
left join tbl t on t.issue=i.issue and t.status=s.status
```

Comment: Fantastic answer. I was able to take this and easily expand it to my needs, simply by adding more rows of `cross join` for additional unique columns I have and then more `t.col=i.col` for the final join. So clearly written and concise, bravo!

Answer (score -1):

You can easily add another row by using this sql command.

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

for instance if your tables name is